# 3D Chemistry laboratory images for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, vuforia

I really wish someone out there has a link to help me out with a link to free 3d animated models for Unity, I'd like to incorporate these 3D chemistry laboratory objects like, test tube, burette, Conical flask, beaker. I really wish there is someone out there to give a heads up, i'm not good at any 3d program to build these by myself.
Please your positive contributions will be most welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Archeopterix' Labware Props for Poser-Vol One:
http://www.sharecg.com/v/66895/browse/11/Poser/Archeopterix-Labware-Props-for-Poser-Vol-One
Microscope:
https://free3d.com/3d-model/microscope-64352.html
Feel free to add to my answer if you find anything else.